# Is there is any way to build the Conan without cmake

Tags: cmake, conan

I just started to explore both conan and cmake for building and packaging C++ files. Here is a sample conanfile.py

```
 from conans import ConanFile, CMake


class PocoTimerConan(ConanFile):
   settings = "os", "compiler", "build_type", "arch"
   requires = "Poco/1.7.8p3@pocoproject/stable"
   generators = "cmake", "gcc", "txt"
   default_options = {"Poco:shared": True, "OpenSSL:shared": True}

   def imports(self):
      self.copy("*.dll", dst="bin", src="bin") # From bin to bin
      self.copy("*.dylib*", dst="bin", src="lib") # From lib to bin

   def build(self):
      cmake = CMake(self)
      cmake.configure()
      cmake.build()
```

Is there any option to build the same without the use of cmake. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the [introduction](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/introduction.html) they say: "**Conan works with any build system**. In the documentation, CMake will be widely used, because it is portable and well known. But Conan does not depend on CMake at all; it is not a requirement." So yes, you may use Conan without CMake.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Conan is [Cross platform, build system agnostic](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/introduction.html#cross-platform-build-system-agnostic)

There is a [list](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/integrations.html) with all integrations available, which includes MS Build, QMake and Autotools.

If you don't want to use integration tools, you can run directly the build commands, including running the compiler commands:

```
def build(self):
    self.run("gcc ...")
```

Answer (score 1):

No, Conan uses whatever build system the library is using, wrapping it. In this case, Poco is using the CMake build system, so CMake is necessary to build it. It is not possible to replace a given build system by another one automatically, that level of automation does not exist.

That doesn't mean that Conan needs CMake to operate. Conan can work with any build system, including proprietary ones. For example:

- [Creating and using packages with Visual Studio](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/howtos/visual_studio_packages.html)
- [Create and reuse packages with Makefiles](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/howtos/makefiles.html)
- [How to create integrations for new and custom build systems](https://blog.conan.io/2019/07/24/C++-build-systems-new-integrations-in-Conan-package-manager.html)

Also, take into account that the build system used to create the package can be different to the one to consume that package. Conan "generators" can generate files for the consuming build system on the fly.

Maybe you are interested in the concept of "build-requires". You can use Conan to automatically install the cmake version that you want as a Conan package, and use it, injecting it automatically to packages to be build. Check the documentation [of "build-requires" here](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/devtools/build_requires.html)